# ZF2 - override gettext translations

Tags: php, zend-framework2, gettext

I'm working on a Zend Framework 2 project which uses gettext (mo/po) files for translation. For each language I have one translations file.

Is it possible to override some of the existing default translations just for certain clients? So for example: all clients will have `translate('Cancel')` translated into `Cancel`, except one client which will load the default translation plus an additional .mo file so that `translate('Cancel')` translates into `Give up`. How can this be done?

Only some labels should have different translation. I don't want to load a different file for each customer but to load only additional override translations for certain clients.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a client only uses a single language, this is trivial: make up a new language to serve to a client. This language would differ from the base language only to the extent specified by the client. It becomes easier if the base language is the key language as you only need to include those specific translations in your language. The difficult part is to do client specific language  detection.

Comment: Client can have multiple languages. There is en.mo, fr.mo, es.mo files for example, each containing complete translation of all site labels. What I want to do is to have additional files en_myclient.mo for example which will contain only couple of labels that are already defined in en.mo, but client want's them labeled differently on his site.

Comment: exactly! that client only uses english so copy en.po to custom.po, make the requested changes, and compile. Then in your code where you initialize gettext, check for this client and set your language to custom. You may need to find a two letter code that is not used to use instead of custom. The fact that your other clients are using multiple languages is not an issue as long as you don't break the language detection when this client is not detected.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to create and maintain two or more translations for each language? Is it possible to have custom.mo as an override for en.mo, so that en.mo contains all translations and is always loaded, while custom.mo contains only couple of labels redefined and is loaded only for certain client. I assume that I'll get conflicts in that case.